# Grab from table values

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.5

This is my table dataset:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 2    7    5    3
 11   18    31  7
```

Those are id's and need to use them as id to grab the name at them associated.
if i do:

```
select table1.name from table1,table2 where table2.id = 1
```

Gives me the name associated to id 1.
I want to automatically grab the names based on the id's in my table in this form.

```
  name1     name2       name3    name4
 name_id2  name_id7   name_id5 name_id3
```

There is a way to obtain this?

---------AS ASKED EXAMPLE

Table1:

```
col2 col3 col4
 2     3    4  
 2     5    6
```

Table2:

```
nome  id
 all   1
 dis1  2
 dis3  3
 dis4  4
 dis5  5
 dis6  6
```

My_result:

```
col2 col3 col4
 dis2 dis3 dis4
 dis2 dis5 dis6
```

Comment: How many tables are involved here? Table1, table2 and also dataset? Add sample table data for all tables involved, and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT T2_1.nome as col2, T2_2.nome as col3, T2_3.nome as col4
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 as T2_1 on T2_1.ID=Table1.col2
LEFT JOIN Table2 as T2_2 on T2_2.ID=Table1.col3
LEFT JOIN Table2 as T2_3 on T2_3.ID=Table1.col4
```

Comment: This is perfect, but there is a way to optimize this? I've 14 of this left joins to do ....

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
SELECT t_name1.nome, t_name2.nome, t_name3.nome
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 t_name1 ON table1.col2 = t_name1.id
LEFT JOIN table2 t_name2 ON table1.col3 = t_name2.id
LEFT JOIN table2 t_name3 ON table1.col4 = t_name3.id
```